# Excluding the same group from multiple dependencies in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-gradle-3.1.0

I have the following code in the build.gradle in the app module of my Android project

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
})
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
})
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
})
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1',  {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
})
```

The firebase libraries all contain a conflicting version of the android support library which I am using and so I need to exclude it to prevent the build warning

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).
```

Is there a way I can group these implementation statements together so I only need to write one exclude statement?

**EDIT**

My specific solution based on Cris' answer

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            details.useVersion '27.1.1'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated on the official [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#example_excluding_transitive_dependency_for_a_particular_configuration), you can achieve that as follows:

```
configurations {
    implementation {
        exclude group: 'javax.jms', module: 'jms'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.jdmk', module: 'jmxtools'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.jmx', module: 'jmxri'
    }
}
```

Another option, is to force a specific version of the group of libraries, support in this case. This is also covered by the [official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html#example_forcing_a_consistent_version_for_a_group_of_libraries)

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'org.gradle') {
            details.useVersion '1.4'
            details.because 'API breakage in higher versions' 
            //note that details.because requires Gradle version 4.6 or higher
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to also cause the support library itself to be excluded.

Comment: @Moses the answer has been edited to add an option to force a specific version

Comment: the `details.because` method causes the following exception `No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.dependencysubstitution.DefaultDependencyResolveDetails.because() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Prevent different versions of android support library contained in other dependencies from conflicting with the one defined in this build.gradle]
Possible solutions: isCase(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)` but after removing that line it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Moses `details.because` was added on version 4.6, according to the [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html), are you using an older version?

Comment: I'm using the most up to date version Android supports. That usually lags behind the latest version of gradle.

Comment: links broken...

Answer (score 0):

I usually take care of this error by putting this in the gradle file:

```
// use default version for all support repositories
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion 'PUT_THE_VERSION_YOU_WANT' //latest would be 28.0.0-rc02
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might have to add `multiDexEnabled` true inside `android`. What this basically does is force everything to use a specific version, so they won't have any conflicts.